# Async Function Only Updating One "Await"

Tags: c#, xaml, asynchronous, async-await

Excuse my ignorance on this subject, but I'm not schooled in asynchronous programming. However, I believe my code is close to achieving what I need it to do.

Basically the code below only works for the very first

```
C61 = new BridgeViewModel("C61");
await C61.Initialize();
```

statements. None of the other items are returning any data to the bound .xaml and I have no idea why. Does each one need to be in its own Initialize function?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
namespace SentinelApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var vm = new MainViewModel();
            DataContext = vm;
            vm.Initialize();
        }
    }

    public class MainViewModel
    {
        public readonly string[] Bridges = { "C61", "C62", "C63", "C68", "C69", "K71", "K72", "K73", "K74", "T91", "GN01", "GE01", "GA01" };
        public async Task Initialize()
        {
            C61 = new BridgeViewModel("C61");
            await C61.Initialize();
            C62 = new BridgeViewModel("C62");
            await C62.Initialize();
            C63 = new BridgeViewModel("C63");
            await C63.Initialize();
            C68 = new BridgeViewModel("C68");
            await C68.Initialize();
            C69 = new BridgeViewModel("C69");
            await C69.Initialize();
            K71 = new BridgeViewModel("K71");
            await K71.Initialize();
            K72 = new BridgeViewModel("K72");
            await K72.Initialize();
            K73 = new BridgeViewModel("K73");
            await K73.Initialize();
            K74 = new BridgeViewModel("K74");
            await K74.Initialize();
            T91 = new BridgeViewModel("T91");
            await T91.Initialize();
            GA01 = new BridgeViewModel("GA01");
            await GA01.Initialize();
            GE01 = new BridgeViewModel("GE01");
            await GE01.Initialize();
            GN01 = new BridgeViewModel("GN01");
            await GN01.Initialize();
        }

        public BridgeViewModel C61 { get; set; }
        public BridgeViewModel C62 { get; set; }
        public BridgeViewModel C63 { get; set; }
        public BridgeViewModel C68 { get; set; }
        public BridgeViewModel C69 { get; set; }
        public BridgeViewModel K71 { get; set; }
        public BridgeViewModel K72 { get; set; }
        public BridgeViewModel K73 { get; set; }
        public BridgeViewModel K74 { get; set; }
        public BridgeViewModel T91 { get; set; }
        public BridgeViewModel GA01 { get; set; }
        public BridgeViewModel GE01 { get; set; }
        public BridgeViewModel GN01 { get; set; }
    }

    public class BridgeViewModel : ViewModel
    {
        private readonly ClientWrapper _client;
        private readonly string _bridge;
        private readonly Timer _timer = new Timer();
        public BridgeViewModel(string bridge)
        {
            _client = new ClientWrapper();
            _bridge = bridge;
        }

        public async Task Initialize()
        {
            await _client.Connect(_bridge);
            await _client.SendMessage(new SessionStart("3", "25").CreateBridgeMessage());

            _timer.Interval = 1000;
            _timer.Elapsed += Update;
            _timer.Start();
        }

        private async void Update(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            try {
                var response = await _client.SendMessage("BS~RESERVE~STATS~REQ~" + _bridge + "~0");
                var split = response.Split('~');

                Timestamp = split[4].Substring(0, 2) + ":" + split[4].Substring(2, 2) + ":" + split[4].Substring(4, 2);
                FreePorts = split[6];
                LongestHold = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(int.Parse(split[15])).ToString("hh:mm");
                Bells = split[12];
                Signals = split[8];
            } catch { }
        }

        private string _timestamp;
        public string Timestamp
        {
            get { return _timestamp; }
            set { _timestamp = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private string _bells;
        public string Bells
        {
            get { return _bells; }
            set { _bells = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private string _signals;
        public string Signals
        {
            get { return _signals; }
            set { _signals = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private string _freeports;
        public string FreePorts
        {
            get { return _freeports; }
            set { _freeports = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private string _longesthold;
        public string LongestHold
        {
            get { return _longesthold; }
            set { _longesthold = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you intending for your view models to initialize sequentially or do you want them to do it at the same time? Check to see if any exceptions are getting caught in the empty `catch` clause in your `Update` method.

Comment: It seems _timer will run indefinitely. I don't know how you finish _timer's task without using Stop() func?

Comment: @NedStoyanov All at the same time. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: @QuanNguyen Is that the issue, that it keeps updating the first one in an infinite loop?

Comment: @NedStoyanov I'm getting a lot of this...

System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.\
at System.Globalization.TimeSpanFormat.FormatCustomized(TimeSpan value, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi)
   at System.Globalization.TimeSpanFormat.Format(TimeSpan value,String format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
at SentinelApp.BridgeViewModel.<Update>d__5.MoveNext() in ....
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format

Comment: @QuanNguyen Hmm...  Do you know how someone would get around that in this situation?

Comment: First find and solve the cause for  all those exceptions...

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using your async method inside a constructor, register and use it inside the [`FrameworkElement.Loaded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded(v=vs.110).aspx) event where you can `await`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += InitializeOnLoaded;
}

public async void InitializeOnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var vm = new MainViewModel();
    DataContext = vm;
    await vm.InitializeAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please expand? The following code oddly enough only loads the 2nd bridge instead of the 1st this time, and if I change "await vm.Initialize();" to "await vm.InitializeAsync();" it tells me that the MainViewModel contains no definition.
        `public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += InitializeOnLoaded;
        }

        public async void InitializeOnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var vm = new MainViewModel();
            DataContext = vm;
            await vm.Initialize();
        `}

Comment: @Brady Then something is wrong with your `Initialize` method. It should work

Comment: I ended up taking out all the "await"s before each "initialize()" and it seems to be working now.